# Как лучше выводить древовидное меню?

Tags: php, mysql

Исходя из модели mvc не понимаю как лучше выводить древовидное меню. Допустим контроллер или модель формирует рекурсивно дерево меню, но потом в виде мне повторно нужно использовать рекурсию, чтобы обойти этот массив. Две рекурсии - плохо для производительности. Писать теги прямо в модели или контроллере - тоже плохо, так как часто нужно их менять для разных типов вывода (категории, выпадающие списки и т.д.) Что делать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте деревья без рекурсии, типа [NestedTree](http://habrahabr.ru/post/153861/) или Materialized Path

Answer (score 2):

Либо деревья без рекурсии (см соседний ответ), либо стройте дерево и кешируйте его где-нибудь. 
Например можно закешировать уже непосредственно блок вывода меню в виде(view).
Подробности уже зависят от использованных средств(фреймворка).

Comment: естественно кешировал, но сервис ложиццо уже после первого захода, еще до того как срабатывает кеш. Там категорий 6 уровней вложенности категорий и их всего около 300

Comment: Пересмотрите алгоритм, стройте и кешируйте по частям (по уровням, по веркам и тд. Строить можно по АЯКС запросам веток, например), перейдите на деревья без рекурсии...
И вы уверены, что вам в меню нужно 300 пунктов? Обычно такое кол-во неудобно.